# What's a good pose estimation method for high precision (<5mm per-axis) solutions at short range (<50cm)?

Tags: sensors, ultrasonic-sensors, pose

I'm trying to get a 6DOF pose solution for an object that'll be between 10 and 50 cm from a fixed point. I want to avoid putting too much special hardware on the object, but extra hardware on the fixed side is fine.

I've been looking into two general methods:

- **fiducial markers** There are several software packages with different types of markers, but I haven't been able to find any information about them regarding precision or accuracy in short-range pose sensing.
- **ultrasonics** I've found some commercial systems that do 6DOF pose sensing (e.g. [hexamite](http://hexamite.com/)), but they're expensive and require you to put transmitters on the object.

Answer (score 2):

The accuracy of fiducial markers (i.e. [glyphs](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/posit/)) depends on your camera's resolution, noise ratio, focus, and field of view.  Essentially, you will need to ensure that there are enough pixels in the recorded image to represent the real-world precision that you want.

To make this easier, it would help if the glyphs are as large as possible and the camera is aimed as "tightly" as possible on the subject.  For a camera with a known resolution and field of view, you should be able to calculate the pixels-per-cm that the images represent (given 10cm and 50cm distances to the subject).  Assume ±2 pixels possible measurement error, and calculate the precision from that.